# Prove that the integral of logarithm of certain function goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

In the comp exam on real analysis this morning, I failed in proving this problem

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $\|f\|_{L^1}=c\in(0,\infty)$ and let $\alpha$ be a fixed number that $0<\alpha<1$.Prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} n\log\left(1+\left(\frac{|f|}{n}\right)^\alpha\right)dm=\infty$$
>   Here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I tried using the inequality for $\log(1+x)>x-\frac{x^2}{2}$. But I couldn't say anything about the integration of $|f|^\alpha$ and $|f|^{2\alpha}$. I tried various inequalities, but none of them works. So I'd appreciate if anyone could give me a hint or solution of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: You need to know more about $f$. Otherwise take $f\equiv 0$ to get $\lim=0$.

Comment: @A.G. Oh yeah, I'm sorry, I have missed a condition.

Comment: Can you find $E\subset\mathbb{R}$: $m(E)>0$ and $0<\epsilon\le|f|\le C$ a.e. on $E$? Then $\int_\mathbb{R}\ge\int_E\sim\int_En^{1-\alpha}|f|^\alpha\,dm\ge n^{1-\alpha}\epsilon^\alpha m(E)\to\infty$.

Comment: Using $\log(1+x)\geqslant x/2$ for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, one gets the lower bound $$\frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{2}\int |f|^\alpha\,\mathbf 1_{|f|\leqslant n}\,dm.$$ Can you conclude?